# Django Testing With Selenium

Tags: django, testing

After running this test the user data persists and is in the default table. My understanding was that a test table would be created and all data in it would be destroyed after the tests run. Can someone explain to me why the data is going to the default table?

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

class AccountSignUpTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.close()

    def test_can_a_user_signup(self):

        self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000/accounts/signup/')

        email = self.browser.find_element_by_name('email')
        email.send_keys('test@example.com')

        first_name = self.browser.find_element_by_name('first_name')
        first_name.send_keys('FName')

        last_name = self.browser.find_element_by_name('last_name')
        last_name.send_keys('LName')

        password1 = self.browser.find_element_by_name('password1')
        password1.send_keys('xxxxxx')

        password2 = self.browser.find_element_by_name('password2')
        password2.send_keys('xxxxxx')

        timezone = Select(self.browser.find_element_by_name('timezone'))
        timezone.select_by_value('America/Phoenix')

        self.browser.find_element_by_id('submit').click()

        assert self.browser.title == 'Login'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not isolating the test. To run this test you need to have `./manage.py runserver` running. So, you are using the development database. To use selenium probably you what that your test inherits from [`LiveServerTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase).

And then change the get request to use the live server url

```
 self.browser.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/accounts/signup'))
```

Comment: Thank You my brilliant friend!